# Re-Render View after CLOSE

Tags: php, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/jobs',
    'text!templates/jobs/list.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, JobCollection, JobListTemplate){
    var JobWidget = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#bbJobList',
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'detect_scroll');
            $(window).scroll(this.detect_scroll);
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.jobCollection = new JobCollection();
        },
        render: function () {
            this.loadResults();
        },
        loadResults: function () {
            var that = this;
            // we are starting a new load of results so set isLoading to true
            this.isLoading = true;

            this.jobCollection.fetch({
                success: function (jobs) {

                    $(that.el).append(_.template(JobListTemplate, {jobs: jobs.models, _:_}));
                    // Now we have finished loading set isLoading back to false
                    that.isLoading = false;
                }
            });
        },
        close: function(){
            this.remove();
            this.unbind();
        }
    });
    return JobWidget;
});
```

How do i remove RELOAD render after i close it? 
I'm planning to Re-Render , the update data are in model which i will grab out from controller(If it's possible)

I tried

```
this.render()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are planning to re-render the view you shouldn't assign el to the prototype, like `el: '#bbJobList'`.

While instantiating the view, append view to the element like

```
 var view = new JobWidget();
 view.render();
 view.$el.appendTo('#bbJobList');
```

after closing view which remove view from the DOM, to re-render the view, instantiate it again as above.

Comment: Thank you. Now i'm left with getting data from my model :)